# VirtualMin: Change Postfix settings.. but for only one website?

Tags: email, server, configuration, smtp

We are hosting about multiple websites on a current Virtualmin server and are using PostFix -> SendGrid to forward emails.

We are going to add a large new website on the server. The problem is that this website needs to use a separate Sendgrid account.

We could change this line in the Postfix config, but it would change for all websites:
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

Is there a way to change it only for a specific website? Any ideas on how we could do this? We could use a different PHP version if that would be any help?